# Pycharm output limit exceeded

Tags: python, pycharm

I wrote a python code to scrap data. But the output window over rights the previous output after a few 1000 lines. The data i am scrapping is over a million lines.  I use pycharm by jetbeans. What are some IDE's or methods which support a million lines of output?

Comment: What are you doing with 1M+ printed lines? Would it be more helpful to output the results of the scraping to a file instead of the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36771541/pycharm-output-limit-exceeded#comment61120355_36771541), the way you've described this seems incorrect. Throwing 1M+ lines to console doesn't *do* anything for you, other than printing a million lines. If you wanted to use this information later, you wouldn't be able to. Instead, you should be sending this data to a file of some kind so that you can use it later.

---

That being said, you *can* increase the output buffer in PyCharm via the following process:

- Click "Help"
- Click "Edit Custom Properties"
- This will either open a file or ask you to create one if the `idea.properties` file doesn't exist. Click "Yes" in that case.
- Add `idea.cycle.buffer.size=2048` to the file

This is not completely disabling the buffer, but instead doubling it from the default 1024kb to 2048kb. Feel free to adjust as appropriate.

Restart PyCharm for these setting to be utilized.

Comment: thanks but i am having trouble in writing it into a file directly. I just started with python . please look at my code(similar one) and please help me by telling how to modify the code so it writes the output directly to a file . I want that to be written into a .csv or .txt file btw https://ghostbin.com/paste/g9ev8

Comment: @MikeSmith, that is a separate question from the one you've posted here about console output. If you have problems writing to a file, I suggest creating a new question and including the code from your ghostbin in the question to show what you've attempting. Explain what is/isn't happening and the errors.