# Why is BeautifulSoup losing so much content from this webpage?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pycharm, lxml

I have a webscraper I built a year ago. I need to use it again but bs4 seems to be acting differently. It used to return a soup object containing the whole webpage, but now it stops short in the middle of a list. I need to get all the list items, so this has broken my old code.

I've looked for similar issues with beautiful soup, and one person on here did have a similar issue, but the solution (to select a specific div element) won't work for me because I need the whole webpage worth of content to scrape all the urls.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def siteopen(url):
    web_source = url
    source_code = requests.get(web_source)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "lxml")
    return soup


print(siteopen('http://celt.ucc.ie/irlpage.html'))
```

`plain_text` contains all the html I want to scrape, however, the `soup` element doesn't contain all of it. It stops short after a list item, apparently randomly.

I'm running this code in PyCharm Community Edition. Would there be some size limit set there, maybe? Otherwise, how can I fix this problem and access the complete soup object?

Edit:

Because others have had success running this in linux and PyCharm Pro, I tried running it in the mac OS terminal, and the problem is recreated there. At the same point where I have a problem in PyCharm the output does this:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure `plain_text` contains all the html?  Have you actually printed it?

Comment: can you provide the url and indicate which urls within it you are after?

Comment: If I run the code you've posted it seems to always return a complete web page.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on mint Python 2 or 3. I get everything printed to `</html>`. When printing in Python 3 directly I get an ASCII error - which is fixed by encoding it to `utf8`. Could PyCharm be hiding this somehow?

Comment: @JohnGordon `plain_text` definitely contains all the html. I think the issue is to do with PyCharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problem seeing all of the data for that request.  Perhaps PyCharm is limiting the amount of text it's allowing to be displayed on a single print.

You can verify this by running

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def siteopen(url):
    web_source = url
    source_code = requests.get(web_source, verify=False)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "lxml")
    return soup


print("</html>" in str(siteopen('http://celt.ucc.ie/irlpage.html')))
```

If you get back a True you know it's pulled the entire page.

Check this to see if you can increase the output buffer limit:

[Pycharm output limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36771541/pycharm-output-limit-exceeded)

Comment: It does return true. I had already set the buffer to 2048, but I doubled it to 4096, and it makes no difference.

Comment: Well at least you know all of your data is there :)  Might wanna reach out to JetBrains to figure out why PyCharm is acting funny.  FWIW it displays correctly in PyCharm Pro for me.

Comment: Just ran it in terminal and had a problem at the same point, so actually I don't think it's PyCharm. Edited the post above to show.

Comment: Try using html.parser instead of lxml, and then print(soup.prettify())

Comment: That worked perfectly. Don't know why lxml would cause that, though.